# Sharing an app that is on a facebook fan page

Tags: facebook

Afternoon,

I have a facebook application that i have added to a facebook fan page, this application has an URL like http://facebook.com/fanPage?sk=app_id. Now i if copy this link and try and share it on the facebook fan page it uses the description/image from the page and not from the application like it want.

Is there any way to change this? The correct meta tags are in place.

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is a way, but not directly. facebook always fetches the meta tags of the top page, as your app runs in an iframe its not fetched.

but you can submit a wallpost (as user or as a fanpage) via the api and give alle information you want. (like image, video, description, title, ....)

see http://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/feed for an example.

An other variant:
You add a canvas app beside your facebook app. (see the app settings) on this page you add the meta tags for the wallposts, and a javascript which redirects to the fanpage like

```
top.location.href = 'http://www.facebook.com/mypage?sk=app_id'
```

when ever you want to share you use the canvas app url. Facebooks greper ignores the javascript redirects but read the meta tags. A user clicking the wallpost is automaticly redirected to the fanpage - tab.

Comment: Great idea, i created a file that included the meta tags and the js redirect and put it on the hosting and then just shared that link. Worked a treat.